# Can't open .NET 4.0.1 targeted project in Visual studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a legacy project which targets .net 4.0.1, and I can't change it to 4.5 because of its huge dependency.

I only have visual studio 2012 on my machine, now I am trying to open it. Visual studio ask me to install 4.0.1, I follow to install it, and then it ask me to install visual studio 2010 sp1 first, I try to install sp1. Of course it failed because i don't have visual studio 2010 installed.

What should I do?

Comment: Ouch.  Microsoft made a big mistake allowing targeting 4.0.1.  You can try Microsoft Support but they'll almost surely tell you to update to 4.5 or use VS2010SP1.  You are going to have to bite this bullet sooner or later, sooner is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite hard to track it down, but you can still download the Multi-Targeting Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.1 (KB2495638) here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27757.

This does work with VS2012 (unlike the one VS2012 tries to download for you).

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question:

Manually change the TargetFrameworkVersion from 4.0.1 to 4.0 in the project .csproj file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>.
```

Just like Hans said we can't make visual studio 2012 work with 4.0.1. but 4.0.1 is very close to 4.0. I think as long as you can compile the project without errors 4.0 should be OK. It works in my case.